# Как сделать запрос по id?

Tags: python, json, requests, discord.py

```
id = ""
r = requests.get(f'https://tanksblitz.ru/ru/api/rating-leaderboards/user/{id}/', headers = HEADERS)
data = r.json()
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при вводе команды человек указывал свой id и оно записывалось в ссылку. Из запроса мне надо получить только "number", "nickname", "score", "clan_tag"

Comment: И что не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Для начала - у вас указан несуществующий HEADERS в параметре запроса. Могу предложить лишь подобное решение:

```py
id = input("Введите ID: ")
r = requests.get(f'https://tanksblitz.ru/ru/api/rating-leaderboards/user/{id}/')
data = r.json()
print(f'Number: {data.number}\nNickname: {data.nickname}\nScore: {data.score}\nClan Tag: {data.clan_tag}')
```

Для более развёрнутого ответа попрошу чуть подробнее описать проблему